# How does Multi-Signature Pay 2 Script Hash (P2SH) enable stronger security?

Tags: transactions, exchanges, script, hash

[Coinfloor](http://blog.coinfloor.co.uk/) says it will pay out withdrawals using Multi-Signature Pay 2 Script Hash.  What is Multi-Signature Pay 2 Script Hash?  I read [What is "Script Hash" address exactly and how does it work?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9678/what-is-script-hash-address-exactly-and-how-does-it-work) but didn't understand how it enables more secure withdrawals form cold storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Multi-signature** is a feature to protect against theft.

[From securing your wallet](https://bitcoin.org/en/secure-your-wallet)

> Bitcoin includes a multi-signature feature that allows a transaction
>   to require the signature of more than one private key to be spent. It
>   is currently only usable for technical users but a greater
>   availability for this feature can be expected in the future.
>   Multi-signature can, for example, allow an organization to give access
>   to its treasury to its members while only allowing a withdrawal if 3
>   of 5 members sign the transaction. It can also allow future online
>   wallets to share a multi-signature address with their users, so that a
>   thief would need to compromise both your computer and the online
>   wallet servers in order to steal your funds.

Traditional Bitcoin addresses are secured with a single private key. P2SH addresses can associated with three private keys. Depositing funds into is the same as depositing funds into a standard Bitcoin address. However, withdrawing funds from the address requires at least 2 of the 3 keys to sign.